# Execute javascript method named on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

**The Objective:**

Execute a javascript function on $.ajax named on server side and get it on result.

**The Problem:**

On data.ExecuteClientCode I'll get the name of the function that I should execute in that case :  "AfterFamilySelectedUpdateParameters()" but my problem is that i don't know how to set that string in order to be executed.

**The code:**

view:

```
function AfterFamilySelected()
           {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "/@Model.ControllerAfterEntitySelected/@Model.ActionAfterEntitySelected" ,
                        type: "POST",
                        async: false,
                        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                                     **data.ExecuteClientCode;**
                                  },
                        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
           }
```

controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AfterFamilySelected() 
        {
            return Json(new { ExecuteClientCode = "AfterFamilySelectedUpdateParameters()" });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the method is attached to the window you could do:

**Server**

```
 HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AfterFamilySelected() 
 {
    return Json(new { ExecuteClientCode = "AfterFamilySelectedUpdateParameters" });
 }
```

**Client**

```
 var callback = window[data.ExecuteClientCode];
 if (callback)
     callback();
```

You would need to remove the brackets from the value you return from the server.

Comment: When you declare public methods in JavaScript they are attached to the `window` object (unless you specify otherwise). All JS objects are index-able :)